# Use a workflow to create a NEW SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to build a workflow that creates a new list for me. Based on certain conditions on the original list, the workflow should build me a new list, which will have text, number, and lookup columns.

[After doing some research](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/), I found that you may be able to use the HTTP Web Service (or called "Call Web Service") in SharePoint Designer to create the list. However, I am not sure if this web service is feasible or would allow me to create the new list.

On a side note: we do not use any third party applications like Nintex or MS Flow, so completing this task can only be done within the confines of SharePoint 2013. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Call HTTP Web Service to utilise SharePoint's REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/). This means you can [use the REST API to create a list in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-lists-by-using-rest).

**Edit:** Some additional information regarding list templates and an article that may be of help

The REST API allows you to create a lists based on out of the box templates e.g. Calendar, Tasks etc. You will need to set the BaseTemplate in your request to the template ID, a list of template IDs can be found here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf

The article below discusses how to create a list from a SharePoint workflow using the Call HTTP Web Service action in more depth:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

Comment: I appreciate it. I will give this a shot. By any chance, do you know if you can use this REST API to create a list based off a list template?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I have updated my answer with additional information and an article that may help you achieve your requirement.